Evidence of Kant being influenced by Adam Smith, on the subject of specialization
Kant, in his Foundations for the Metaphysics of Morals (Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten - 1785), defends the benefits of specialization for philosophers and theorists. It is a very curious positioning, within the Enlightenment. There are, however, reports that he managed to establish himself at the university by publishing freely in times of monarchical dictatorship through this separation between his philosophical concerns and the rest of knowledge, without necessarily needing to distill consequences of what he wrote to sensitive issues of religion and politics.
His philosophical debate with Hume is of fundamental importance, recognized by Kant. "The Wealth of Nations" in 1776, well within the decade in which Kant was "silent", without publishing.
Does anyone have any references, letters, or indications of Adam Smith's influence on Kant?

Fleischacker noted those division of labor passages too. Herz, Kant's friend and confidant, wrote in a letter that Smith is Kant's "favorite", and Kant directly quotes Wealth of Nations in Metaphysics of Morals, indicating that he adopted Smith's labor theory of value. Smith is also mentioned by name in Anthropology from a Pragmatic Point of View, and his chief German expositor, Kraus, was a student and friend of Kant's.  See Richardson for Smith's influence on Kant's moral philosophy.
